# is the installation hang-up for pc with multiple harddrive and partitions present in 12.10 is fixed in 13.04?

Tags: installation, 12.10, 13.04

i pc has 3 hard drive with several partition in each drives ? in 12.10 the installation crashes right after you click next on the 1st language selection box. it looks like parted or something related failed. i heard this does not happen if you have only 1 hard drive. hoping they will fix it in 13.04.

Comment: Please posta layout of those discs if you want to see if it is fixable. 3 discs in itself is nothing the installer should make problems about. There needs to be another problem.

Comment: nah. its a bug with the installer. u can disconnect the drives. keeping only one. the installer works fine. its not fixed in 13.04 euther.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered this problem when shifting from 12.04 to a clean install of 13.04 with twin hard disks and a dual-boot to Windows.  The 'Disk Setup' stage refused to recognise existing partitions or free space.  Partman usually exited with error code 141 but sometimes crashed.  I lost three days days of my life and became intimately acquainted with testdisk.

Eventually I tracked the fault to the existence of dmraid metadata on the two hard drives.  It was not shown up by testdisk but was listed by dmraid.  Using **dmraid -rE** to erase the unnecessary metadata meant that the ubiquity install routine functioned normally.